# Fastest way to get the height of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

**The situation**

I've created an HTML "book" where every page is a div:

[image]

The divs have all absolute position's because they have to be on top of each other.

Now the height of the book has to be that of the highest page. So I've created an "heightkeeper" div which has "visibility:hidden" so the heightkeeper div is never visible but keeps the height of the book as height as the highest page.

So far so good, but now...

**The problem**

When the book is initialized I check with JavaScript the height of every page. I get the content of that page and add that to the heightkeeper.

```
$book.find("div.page").each(function () {
                        pageHeight = $(this).height();

                        if (highestPagePx < pageHeight) {
                            highestPagePx = pageHeight;
                            highestPageContent = $(this).html();
                        }
                    });
```

This works perfect in all the modern browsers but now I'm debugging IE8 and this takes a lot of time...
In my virtual machine (which is not fast but old browsers are on old computers) it takes around 40 ms per page. With 10 pages that's almost half a second. With 3 books on a webpage it takes like 1.5 seconds. In my opinion to long.

**Does anybody can come up with a creative solution?**

I was thinking of how to set relative div's on top of each other so the whole heightkeeping stuff is unnecessary. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: actaually, you dont have to position them with absolute positioning, you can put them one after each other like regular div's, with display none, and when you're clicking on 'change page' you change the next page to 'block' and the old one to 'none'. aslo.. you dont have to keep the highest page in the background the whole time to keep the height. you can assing the height to the container once on page load.

Comment: That would be possible but the animations are to complex for it. The pages are turning. In a page turn 4 div's are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try less jQuery :

```
var pages   = $book.find("div.page").get(),
    highest = 0;

for (var i=0; i<pages.length; i++) {
    if ( pages[i].clientHeight > highest) highest = pages[i].clientHeight;
}

for (var i=0; i<pages.length; i++) {
    pages[i].style.height = highest;
}
```

Comment: 7 pages in my old way took 235 - 252 milliseconds.
When I do it this way it takes only 3 - 5 (!!!!!!) ms.. What an improvement. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

i think that this takes a lot of time:
`highestPageContent = $(this).html();`
better get the index of biggest page:
`highestPageContentIndex = $(this).index();`
and outside loop:
`highestPageContent = $("div.page").eq(highestPageContentIndex).html();`

Comment: No the html() part only took about 4 ms. But you are right of doing it outside the loop. So thanks for that!